# GitPython unable to set the git config username and email

Tags: python, git, git-push, gitpython

I am writing a python script that uses GitPython(https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to commit my local files to a remote repository. After making the edits to my files, I set the vaue of username and email as shown in the following snippet:

```
      repo = git.Repo.init("my local clone path")
      repo.config_writer().set_value("name", "email", "myusername").release()
      repo.config_writer().set_value("name", "email", "myemail").release()
      repo.git.add("filename")
      repo.git.commit("filename")
      repo.git.push("my remote repo url")
```

I always encounter the following error:

```
 stderr: '
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
```

Even though I have set my username and password using config_writer() function as mentioned here: http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#handling-remotes

Any suggestions on how to fix this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`set_value` destinations are incorrect here.

```
repo.config_writer().set_value("name", "email", "myusername").release()
repo.config_writer().set_value("name", "email", "myemail").release()
```

These lines have to be like following:

```
repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "name", "myusername").release()
repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "email", "myemail").release()
```

Comment: How can I set git secret here ?

Answer (score -1):

on using this

```
repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "name", "myusername").release()
repo.config_writer().set_value("user", "email", "myemail").release()
```

i got the below error

> "config_writer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'."

i resolved it using

```
os.system("git config --global user.name \"firstname lastname\"")
os.system("git config --global user.email \"youremail@email.com\"")
```

Comment: You have a problem with the `repo` object. It should be an instance of `git.Repo`